# Passing Incoming Http Request in a method Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

I am submitting a form through post method and request goes on controller class
I want to pass this Request in another method. How can i pass this Http Post Request in another method ? this is my form

```
<form method = "Post", action = "/Home/save">
<input type = "text" name ="username" />
<input type = "submit" value = "Send">
</form>

//This is my controller Class
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public String saveData()
        {
             MyClass obj = new MyClass();
             obj.saveData(Here I want to pass incoming Request);
        }

}
```